# Create an excel file on run time with multiple sheets using xlsxwriter and python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, xlsxwriter

```
# running the loop
for row in keywordDF:

    output_file_name = row + ".xlsx"
    output_file_path = root_path + "Output\\" + output_file_name
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, engine='xlsxwriter', options={'in_memory': True})

    for j in template.index:
        partcode = template['Partcode'][j]
        desc = template['Description'][j]
        list1 = []
        list2 = []
        for i in df1.index:
            if(df1['Product Number'][i].__contains__(partcode) & df1['Description'][i].__contains__(row)):

                list1.append(desc + "" + df1['Description'][i])
                list2.append(df1['Product Number'][i])

                final1 = list(zip(list2,list1))
                output = pd.DataFrame(final1, columns = ['Product Number','Description'])
                **print("Output: ", output)** # data is coming in the output


                output.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheets[j], index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')
        writer.save()

print("Process is completed.")
```

**Issue:** Files are getting saved but there is no data inside these excel files. Can you guys please let me know what I am doing wrong and where? When I am printing the data it's get printed.

Comment: You write output to your file inside the for loop. Its possible each run of the loop undoes/overwrites your previous runs. If the last `j` in `template.index` is empty, this would lead to your final files being empty. I would start by moving the final writing outside of the loop.

Comment: Can you please re-write that part of code about which you are talking?